# My validation loss and binary accuracy has overshoots

Tags: neural-networks, keras

I have built MLP network using 10 hidden layers

I am seeing a lot of overshoots in the validation for loss and accuracy.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I have 66 input variables and each hidden layer has 32 nodes and output is binary classification

The overall iterations are improving the loss and accuracy but with each iteration the variation of loss and accuracy is increasing:

[image]

Comment: The variance of the validation accuracy seems to be quite low as it is, so I would not worry about it too much. How large is the validation set? Are these epochs or single iterations?

Comment: Are you using [tag:dropout]? Did you turn off dropout when measuring validation set statistics?

Comment: * dropout is just one example of a regularization technique which needs to be turned off at test time. Others include batch norm and mixup variants.